# Spring Boot - no such column exception

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-batch, informix

I'm writing a Spring Batch / Boot app to extract data from an informix DB to java data object but I cannot figure out a `java.sql.SQLException`: No such column name problem.

This is the method:

```
    public UserDo getUserAddress(UserDo item) {
    try {
        myJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(getUserAddressQuery, new RowMapper<UserDo>() {
            @Override
            public UserDo mapRow(ResultSet rs, int arg1) throws SQLException {
                try {
                    item.setAddressLine1(rs.getString("cad_add_line_1")); 
                    item.setAddressLine2(rs.getString("cad_add_line_2" + "cad_add_line_3" + "cad_add_line_4"));
                    item.setCity(rs.getString("cad_city_name"));
                    item.setState(rs.getString("cad_ste_prv_cd"));
                    item.setZip(rs.getString("cad_postal_code" + "cad_postal_cd_4"));
                    item.setCountry(rs.getString("cad_country_code"));
                } catch (SQLException sqle){
                    logger.error(sqle.getMessage(), sqle);
                }
                return item;
            }
        }, item.getUserId());
    } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException erdae) {
        logger.error(erdae.getMessage(), erdae);
    } catch (IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException irsdae) {
        logger.error(irsdae.getMessage(), irsdae);
    }
    return item;
}
```

This is the query being executed by `JdbcTemplate`:

```
    private final String getUserAddressQuery = "select cad_add_line_1, cad_add_line_2, cad_add_line_3, cad_add_line_4, cad_city_name, cad_ste_prv_cd, cad_postal_code, cad_postal_cd_4, cad_country_code, cad_county_parrish "
        + "from user_address "
        + "where user_id = ? "
        + "and user_type_code = '03' ";
```

The table column values are all of type `CHAR` with column sizes ranging from `3` to `35`.

Data Object properties are all of type String.

This method is called from my `ItemProcessor`.

`ResultSet` object appears to be empty when I am using the debugger. I think the problem is reading from an informix `CHAR` to Java `String`. This is because another method doing the exact same thing, except reading from an informix `INTEGER` to Java `int`, works perfectly.

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
rs.getString("cad_add_line_2" + "cad_add_line_3" + "cad_add_line_4")
```

This will compile to:

```
rs.getString("cad_add_line_2cad_add_line_3cad_add_line_4")
```

And I would strongly suspect no such column exists.

---

Did you mean:

```
rs.getString("cad_add_line_2")
+ rs.getString("cad_add_line_3")
+ rs.getString("cad_add_line_4")
```

---

You have the exact same issue here:

```
rs.getString("cad_postal_code" + "cad_postal_cd_4")
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir. I will accept your answer just as soon as it lets me. If you don't mind me asking another question, is how I'm using / setting the item object in this method ok? This fixed the error but it is still not being written to the file so I think the changes aren't making it's way back to the item processor which passes the item it to the writer.

Comment: Not really, no. You pass in an `item`. You then mutate the `item` in the `myJdbcTemplate.queryForObject` method, and ignore the return value. You then return the same `item`. It's all very confused. I think you need to really think about what object you are receiving to the method, what object you are mutating and what you are returning. I would suggest rewriting the method to accept an `int userId` and then `return myJdbcTemplate.queryForObject`.

Comment: Right again. Using creating new DOs passing them back and re-initializing in calling method to return object is working. Need to think about just passing the int but I appreciate the advice. Goodnight from across the pond.